# Windows7 64 bit on 15" Macbook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, macbook

When I try to install Windows7 with Bootcamp, it mention Windows 32 bit, no word about 64. Can I install Windows7 64 bit Ultimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate is supported. But you need at least [Boot Camp 3.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl979)

Update: I just glanced over Boot Camp documentation and according to it 64 bit compatibility actually depends a bit on your Mac model:

*You can use a 64-bit version of Windows Vista or Windows 7 with any of these
Mac computers:*

*- A Mac Pro or MacBook Pro introduced in early 2008 or later*

*- An iMac or MacBook introduced in late 2009 or later*

Comment: just installed Windows 7 Ultimate x64, even just using Bootcamp from CD and it was newest. works so far, thanks